# Spring Cloud Eureka: changing heartbeat and discovery path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am unable to conjure up a property to change the heartbeat and discovery context for the Eureka server from the ConfigBeans located in github: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/tree/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka

Seems I'm able to set the context path within the client, but not the server.  For example, with a client configured as:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    statusPageUrlPath: /admin/info
    healthCheckUrlPath: /admin/health
    homePageUrlPath: /admin/dashboard
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    eurekaServerUrlContext: /admin
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/admin/eureka/
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
  dashboard:
     path: /admin/dashboard
```

There seems to be nothing in `EurekaServerConfigBean` for me to modify on the server to change the context to `/admin`.  When I run my clients, I get:

```
2015-07-23 12:18:32.069 ERROR 18894 --- [pool-7-thread-1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Can't get a response from http://localhost:8761/admin/eureka/apps/
Can't contact any eureka nodes - possibly a security group issue?
```

Comment: You can hit this url on the eureka server? http://localhost:8761/admin/eureka/apps/ `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` looks like the right way to do this.  We have tests to make sure you can change the eureka context https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/ApplicationContextTests.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So @spencergibb clued me into a test which required the following config within the Eureka Server application.yml:

```
server.contextPath: /admin
```

And that did it.  I was overthinking that it was a eureka.server setting.